# Import cell from another tab

Tags: google-sheets

How can I import a cell from another tab based on one variable? Below is the link to the sample spreadsheet. I would Column A on the Percentages tab to populate the county  name based on the number is Column B.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MSvpMqxhHP6N7ZRGxtaNPF9SYLCCBHDMAz-jX3e1WEQ/edit#gid=0

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please make the spreadsheet public please? I can't see it to help you at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have access to see your sheet, but if I understand correctly, I think you might want to use a VLookup. You function would look something like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,A1:B10,2)
```

- B1 is the "based on the number in column B" cell
- A1:B10 is the range of cells that contains the percentages and county names and any other numbers
- 2 is the column number in the range you would like to return. For example, if the county name is in column B, choose 2.

Note, in case you dont know. You have to add the sheet reference when cells are on a different tab from where you have your calculation. So, the equation may look like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,SheetName!A1A1:B10,2)
```